# How to remove all certificates from cacerts?

Tags: ssl-certificate, keystore, keytool, android-keystore

I know I may use

```
keytool -delete -alias alias -keystore .keystore
```

to remove some certificates from certificate storages. But I've got 109 certificates stored in cacerts: [keytool -list result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znyUt.png)

How to remove them with one command? Or, in other words, how do you clear cacerts storage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no *one* command from `keytool` to delete all the entries in a keystore. You have to do a few workarounds to achieve this.

You can do it either by writing a simple Java code using the `KeyStore` api:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File("KEYSTORE_PATH")), "changeit".toCharArray());

Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();

while (aliases.hasMoreElements())
{
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();

    ks.deleteEntry(alias);
}

ks.store(new FileOutputStream(new File("KEYSTORE_PATH")), "changeit".toCharArray());
```

(Or)

Create a similar store, since you already know the type of `cacerts` keystore (minor workaround here).

1. Create a KeyStore with a keypair initially when creating the `cacerts` keystore file.

> keytool -genkeypair -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit

2. Delete the initially create key pair entry.

> keytool -delete -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -alias mykey

Since the cacerts is the default keystore, you don't specify the other attributes in the keytool command, let java handle the default values for you. Now you should have an empty cacerts keystore.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-2874/6migoia18/index.html

This worked for me:

```
sudo keytool -delete -alias cacertName -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
```

No mentioning that you must know the keystore password of the cacert you are going to delete, otherwise you could not delete it.

Comment: This command will help you to remove certificates one by one. Original question was how to remove them all at once. So, your answer is not suitable, sorry